# Make localhost faster?

Tags: optimization, cakephp, performance, localhost

I am currently working on a project and testing it on my localhost.

The thing I am worried about is that pages are loaded quite slow (500-700ms and not less). I thought localhost would load faster than any other web page (as it resides on my local machine). Therefore, if these are the load times on localhost, would they be significantly bigger when moving my site on a remote server?

As technical details, I am developing on CakePHP framework and have several AJAX requests, all taking the above specified time to load. The requests shouldn't be time-consuming, as they load a CakePHP-generated pages with MySQL operations which take less than 3ms (as shown in the framework's debugger). I am also using XAMPP (therefore Apache webserver) on a Windows 7 machine.

Thank you for your answers and I believe this post would be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're saying MySQL is fast, but the slowdown is purely in PHP, enabling the APC extension may help. APC caches the output of the PHP parser and does a few other optimizations. Often it can save a ton.

But in general, you'll want to do profiling. Use XDebug to get profiling information and use WinCacheGrind to read out where things are slow.

Comment: I don't know whether the slowdown is caused by PHP. Maybe there's a slowdown in Javascript while making the AJAX request. I don't know, something causing the pages not to be found very quickly. Regarding the PHP caching, as far as I know, CakePHP does this by default. Or do I have to enable something in particular?

Comment: If it's the page entirely, use a client-side profiler (Firebug will give you information and YSlow may also help) CakePHP's caching is not the same as APC. APC is a PHP extension that speeds things up in PHP's core.. try it

Comment: So, you say I should use APC besides Cake's caching...? Won't be the two cache systems conflicting?

Comment: Having APC installed is a completely different caching mechanism. Read up on it!

Answer (score 5):

You'll probably see *faster* loading time - it's unlikely your computer is as powerful as a real server.

Personally, I'm always surprised by how much faster my projects run live - but this could depend on the server. You should upload a quick test to ease your worry.

Comment: So, you say that a remote page on a real server may load faster than a page from my local machine? Isn't there supposed to be some kind of lag while communicating remotely?

Comment: Communication lag isn't the only issue.... the computer also has to actually run the script. How well do static pages (i.e. just `.html` no php or ajax) work for you?

Comment: Your computer is a small box running with hardly any steam compared to a farm of machines optimized to serve content over http. You may actually see significant (positive) differences, but it does depend on the server, and its location. The best thing to do it try it and find out, ***then*** decide if it's an issue. Those times you posted are not awfully bad at all.

Comment: OK, I am more relaxed now...I thought that normal load times should be under 100ms. Anyway, I will test it on a real server and then have the final verdict. @Random832: They load in under 30ms.

Comment: Although a decicated webserver might be optmized, there's no reason a powerful development machine can achieve the same results. Especially if we're just talking about raw speed for a single user.

Answer (score 3):

Also bear in mind that when testing you will probably use debug set to greater than 0. When greater then 0 your model structures are not cached making cake reload them on every request

Comment: I forgot to count this fact. It should be faster then if I disable debugging.

Comment: totally forgot about this too. Was a huge issue for me all week when I was changing the db structure and deploying my application